# Remove hover CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to create a class that removes hover css from an element?

Say I have two elements:

```
<div class="orange noHover">Whatever</div>
<div class="blue noHover">Whatever2</div>

.orange {
    color:orange;
}
.orange:hover {
    color:red;
}
.blue {
    color:blue;
}
.blue:hover {
    color:green;
}
.noHover:hover {
    //Remove all hover css applied
}
```

I want the noHover class to behave as if it the orange and blue hover css was never applied to either element. So the orange would always be orange and the blue would always be blue.

Comment: Exactly like you wrote it?  I mean, essentially what you're asking people to do is write a reset for you without knowing what you need to reset.

Comment: Unknown hover? The CSS files shows the :hover

Comment: What is "Normal" hover behaviour? Just apply whatever hover style you want right there where you have the comment...

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains an answer within the question itself. And it's no longer a question.

Comment: @uesports135 No... What is the "default hover css"? You already have exactly what you need. If you put whatever CSS Rule you want exactly where you now have a comment then that will become the hover behaviour on that element. There is no "default hover" other than browser defaults for links and things like that.

Comment: @uesports135 – There's no such thing as what you're asking for.  You need to reset the specific styles applied to the element on hover.  That requires knowledge of what's being applied.  A "default" can't be applied as styles are indeterminate, and often based on the medium (software/hardware) of the device which they're being accessed on.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR That is how to give hover style. I understand. But unless I list EVER possible css there is, then it's not doing what  asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you want the elements to do nothing on hover. That is to say, the maintain whatever styles they normally would have when not hovered. E.g, if they have an orange background when not hovered, you want them to stay orange.

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this with pure css.

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe this isn't exactly what you meant, but it would work:

```
.orange,
.orange.noHover:hover {
    color:orange;
}

.orange:hover {
    color:red;
}

.blue,
.blue.noHover:hover {
    color:blue;
}

.blue:hover {
    color:green;
}
```

Another method, but not compatible with IE8 and below:

```
.orange {
    color:orange;
}
.orange:not(.noHover):hover {
    color:red;
}
.blue {
    color:blue;
}
.blue:not(.noHover):hover {
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: This would work in this case but I was hoping for a class that would override any class. So I wouldn't need to write edge case css for ever element I have hover css applied to.